# Django Window functions

Tags: python, django, window-functions

### Question

How do I calculate the delta of a column between two consecutive rows in my database using the Django ORM?

### Background

I have the following model:

```
class Foobar(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to calculate the delta between `foo` for each row in the database. I found [Django's support for Window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) and the [`Lag()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#lag). With those in hand, I tried something like this:

```
Foobar.objects.annotate(delta=Window(expression=F('foo') - Lag('foo')))
```

which gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/scraper-2Ye6bxs0-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 1275, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expression 'CombinedExpression' isn't compatible with OVER clauses.
```

So to simplify, I just tried to annotate each row with the value from the previous row:

```
fs = Foobar.objects.annotate(prev=Window(expression=Lag('foo'))
for f in fs:
    print(model_to_dict(f))
```

The resulting dicts in my `print()` statement don't have `'prev'`, though. What am I missing? What is the correct way to use `Lag()` to calculate the delta between each row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The resulting dicts in my `print()` statement don't have `'prev'`,
> though.

That is because you are using `model_to_dict` which uses the models declared fields to return a dictionary, of course it doesn't know anything about the data you annotated via your query. If you actually check the model the value does get annotated on it:

```
fs = Foobar.objects.annotate(prev=Window(expression=Lag('foo'))

for f in fs:
    print(f.prev)
```

Moving on for your calculation of the delta you can do it of course, just that `F('foo')` needs to be *outside* the `Window` expression:

```
fs = Foobar.objects.annotate(delta=F('foo') - Window(expression=Lag('foo')))

for f in fs:
    print(f.delta)
```

---

> **Note**: You seem to be using `model_to_dict` for some reason, perhaps for serializing data to use for an API? This is not really a
> great way to serialize models, instead you should look into using
> [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only used `model_to_dict()` to see the results in the Django shell. My actual production code is using DRF serializers or DRF `Response()` for lists or dicts.